# vertx cpu load test with jmeter

Tags: cluster-computing, cpu, vert.x

I am doing a vertx load test with jmeter
But cpu usage does not go up more than 20%

I am using vertx as an http2 serve

I've fixed it in the vertx option but it doesn't go up

What am I doing wrong?

```
  VertxOptions vertxOptions = new VertxOptions();
   vertxOptions.setEventLoopPoolSize(256);
   vertxOptions.setWorkerPoolSize(8);
   vertx = Vertx.vertx(vertxOptions);
```

Comment: How many CPUs do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To utilize multi core processors you need to deploy multiple instances of Verticle.

You can specify the number of verticle instances that you want to deploy.

```
DeploymentOptions options = new DeploymentOptions().setInstances(16);
vertx.deployVerticle("com.mycompany.MyOrderProcessorVerticle", options);
```

> This is useful for scaling easily across multiple cores. For example
>   you might have a web-server verticle to deploy and multiple cores on
>   your machine, so you want to deploy multiple instances to utilise all
>   the cores.